# How to Draw a text in iphone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ios5

Hi.. I have to draw a text @"Hello" on button click action..is it possible 
to draw it.I have the font , size  and color.is their any animation is
required?
   please tell me any refer for code or link.
 ThanksThis is the code which should be followed on button click

```
    -(void)button_Action
   {
      //how to call [drawRect:rect]
   }
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
          [super drawRect:rect];
        //what code have to write 
     }
```

Comment: Is the Stack Overflow and Google search function broken at the moment?

Comment: Its a very simple question, it should be answered somewhere in the site or in google.com

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [NSString UIKit additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), you'll find there all the methods needed to draw a string on the screen.

The methods should be called in `drawRect:` method, and basically you need to call `[myView setNeedsDisplay:YES]` once you need to redraw the view.